# Synthesis of allylic ether, starting with phenalene

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, aromatic-compounds, synthesis, ethers

I stumbled across a retro-synthesis question, for which I don't know the exact answer; I prepared two synthesis ways, but I don't know if they could be realized in a lab. The question is the following:

[image]

Here are my two ways:

[image]

[image]

Are those ways feasible or should I take another approach?

Comment: The method of installing the allyl ether in your top method will not work. NaH + allyl bromide would be better.

Comment: Ah, so basically, the alcohol gets deprotonated, forms an alkoxide ion, and attacks the allyl bromide in an Sn2-reaction to form the ether?

Comment: Exactly so, NaH is easier to handle than sodium metal for creating the alkoxide

Comment: You could also epoxidise the double bond and do a reductive opening to give the same alcohol as in method 1. There are a number of methods for this, catalytic transfer hydrogenation with ammonium formate and Pd/C should work as described here:  https://www.researchgate.net/publication/232995596_Pd-Catalysed_Regiospecific_Reductive_Ring_Opening_of_Epoxides_and_Glycidic_Esters

Comment: In your second solution, the allylic alkoxide is likely to effect E2 elimination on the bromide. Go with @Waylander.

Comment: @Waylander is right. For the top method you need a stronger base and one hydroxyl group to deprotonate, plus another halide where the deprotonated alcohol can attack (hence his suggestion of allyl bromide). NaH should be good enough for deprotonation. In the second method (Williamson synthesis), alkoxide can act as a base and will give significant amounts of elimination product, so though the reaction works, the yield will be low.